Can 2 scheduled batch jobs running in spring boot, on seperate microservices interfere with each other?
I have a strange error occurring in my java spring boot project where I create an @entity database object, and it says that it violates the primary keys uniqueness constraint when being written to the database.  My theory is that this was caused by having 2 jobs scheduled at the exact same time.  My question is as follows: if I have a job scheduled to run at the exact same time as another job and they both create entries to the same database table, can they interfere with one another?  The key here is that they are running on different microservices so spring boot can't tell that they are running at the same time.  I'm thinking that if the jobs created the objects at roughly the exact same time before either was able to write them to the database it might cause the error I'm seeing.  For context, I'm using an Oracle database.  Oracle may be set up to handle this case but I'm not sure.
When I run the jobs at different times this behavior was not replicated.

Do you have the ability to alter the primary key?  If so, you can include an Oracle Sequence to the table, and add that sequence to the primary key, to really make it unique, and transparent to the application.
